# Display checkbox instead of drop down select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, twitter-bootstrap, select

I have the following form:

```
<%= form_for @user  do |f| %>
   <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :extra_act %>
      <%= f.select(:extra_act, [['Act 1', 1],['Act 2', 2], ['Act 3', 3]], class: 'form-control', required: true)  %></br>
   </div>
<%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a way to offer checkboxes instead of the drop down select menu here? I have found checkboxes on the ruby website, but I only want users to have the option of selecting one checkbox.

Comment: You need `radio buttons` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work with `rails 4+`

You want the user to select only one value so instead of `check_box` you need `radio button`. Here is how you can do it(syntax):

```
collection_radio_buttons(method, collection, value_method, text_method, options = {}, html_options = {}, &block)
```

Something like this with your code:

```
f.collection_radio_buttons(:extra_activity_id, ExtraActivity.all, :id, :title, html_options: { class: 'form-control' }
```

For `rails 3` you will need to loop on the extra activities:

```
<% ExtraActivity.all.each do |ea| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :extra_activity_id, ea.id %>
<% end %>
```

As you don't have this is database and you are using an array then do it like this, it may work:

```
f.collection_radio_buttons(:extra_activity_id, [['Act 1', 1],['Act 2', 2], ['Act 3', 3]], :last, :first, html_options: { class: 'form-control' }
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to figure out the syntax - this is what i currently have: `<%=  f.collection_radio_buttons :extra_activity, @user, [[1, 'Personal Activity'] ,[2, 'Physical Activity'], [3, 'Community Activity']], html_options: { class: 'form-control' } %>` Which is wrong.. ` extra_activity` is the variable I am trying to update, and the ids and titles are included in that array, with html options after. I'm getting an error saying `undefined method 'map' for user'

Comment: Instead of `@user` it should be the `Activities` like I have written `ExtraActivity.all` which will fetch all the `extra_activities` from database and then it maps the `id` and `title`.

Comment: I'm editing the attribute `extra_activities` which is an integer belonging to a User object, I don't have any objects called  `ExtraActivity.all` or `Activities`, I just have User. When I use `<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :extra_activity, User.all, [[1, 'Personal Activity'] ,[2, 'Physical Activity'], [3, 'Community Activity']], html_options: { class: 'form-control' } %> ` I'm still getting the mapping error

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a single select list (meaning multiselect attribute should be off) or a radio group.

Whichever suits your needs.